# onConfigurationChanged вызывается два раза подряд

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, почему метод onConfigurationChanged в андроид 7 при первом повороте экрана вызывается два раза подряд, а дальше нормально? При перезапуске приложения снова первый поворот экрана вызывается два раза подряд. Проверял на xiaomi mi a1, на старом самсунге на андроиде 5 все нормально работает.. Как нибудь можно исправить? Может другой какой способ есть вызывать событие при повороте экрана?

Манифест:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

Метод:

```
//отследить поворот экрана
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf("test"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Скорее всего это происходит из-за того, что в атрибуте `android:configChanges` Вы указываете сразу два параметра: `orientation` и `screenSize`. Если оставить только значение `orientation`, то такое поведение должно пропасть. Не знаю почему, но у меня срабатывало. (Стоит отметить, что убрав `screenSize` Вы сможете отслеживать поворот экрана, но не сможете отслеживать изменение размеров экрана при переходе приложения в мультиоконный режим)

2) Возможно, какой-то баг в операционке, попробуй отдебажить и посмотреть стек вызовов методов до того момента как вызывается `onConfigurationChanged`. Это должно объяснить причину двойного вызова метода.

Comment: Если верить [докам](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes?hl=ru#HandlingTheChange), при повороте экрана вызываются оба события и оба приводят к пересозданию активности, поэтому убирать из манифеста - не выход. Вероятно не всегда и не везде они выдаются одновременно (в одном вызове `onConfigurationChanged()`). Выход: проверять интересующий нас параметр `newConfig.orientation` и выполнять логику в зависимости от его значения.